# Battery drain on Cyanogen OS 13.1

Tags: cyanogen-os

I have a OnePlus One running stock Cyanogen OS. Before the upgrade to 13.1, I was getting 24-48 hours of battery life, but now I'm only getting 6-8 hours.

Wiping the system cache doesn't help. Hard reset doesn't help. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Cyanogen OS 13.1. Go to `Settings > Personal > Apps`, open the three dots menu and select `Show system`. Find `Google Contacts Sync` in the list, select, and tap `DISABLE`.

I am not sure as of yet whether this breaks any functionality.

Comment: If you update the contacts on the phone or your Google contacts online, they won't reflect each other.